# Addition of rasters

Tags: python, numpy, raster

I have a list of rasters. I want to do pixel wise addition of the rasters in the list. 
I am using *numpy* and *gdal*. My code is:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np

def fn():
    i0 = r'C:\Add\rst0.tif'
    i1 = r'C:\Add\rst1.tif'
    i2 = r'C:\Add\rst2.tif'
    List = [i0,i1,i2]
    res = []
    res1=[]

    for f in List:
        gd = gdal.Open(f)
        res.append(gd.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())
        arr = np.array(res)
        flat = arr.flatten()
        res1.append(flat) #list of flattened arrays
        print(flat)
        print(res1) #list of flattened arrays
    return res1
    aa = sum(res1)
    print(aa)
```

I get the error for the line:

> TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray'object is not callable

I do not want to do simple `i0+i1+i2` because I am creating a user interface where the number input rasters will be user defined, hence wouldn't be known.

So I have understood that because the list res1 [] is stored as something like [array([0,1,2....3,2,9]), array([1,2,3......6,7,8]), array([1,6,7,......,7,6,9,])] I get the error that object is not callable, because of the structure of the list and the presence of string - 'array' in the list. I am sure there would be a way to get past this. However I am a novice and hence posting it here.

Comment: Variable sum overloads function sum()

Comment: @tstanisl even after changing the variable to something like aa or bb, I get the same   error. I had tried np.add also, that didn't work either. What would you suggest?

Comment: ok.. Please update the code in the question

Comment: Alright I have changed the variable to aa in the updated question

Comment: Variable aa gets overwritten with every iteration. I guess it should be added to some accumulator

Comment: I have put the whole code in a function and used 'return' to get the list of arrays back. But now when I call the function I do not get any result nor any error

Comment: it should return `res1`, `aa` is never computed